# Get Url Alias for Taxonomy Term in a view

Tags: drupal

I created a view which shows all terms from a taxonomy.
I am showing the Tax description as an excerpt with a "more" Link.

For this Link, I want to use the url alias: I tried it this way:

```
[term:url:path]
```

What is the correct replacement pattern for the path alias for the more link path?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

It would be the same! Since you have already selected only trimmed version of the description, its like displaying node teaser and you can use the same link to go to actual page.